# Problem with greek characters using java

Tags: java, encoding

I am trying to write greek characters to a file using java like this:

```
String greek = "\u03c1\u03ae\u03bc. \u03c7\u03b1\u03b9\u03c1\u03b5\u03c4\u03ce";

 try {
         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("E:\\properties\\outfilename.txt"));
         out.write(greek);
         out.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
     }
```

Not working. Tried to use javac -encoding ISO-8859-7. Also tried java -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-7.
Assuming that as I do not have greek font in my pc, I downloaded achillies (greek font - Ach4.ttf).Installed it by going to control panel> fonts. 
Any ideas?

Comment: What are you using to view the file with? Are you sure the problem isn't that Notepad (or whatever) is assuming a different encoding?

Also, why not use a Unicode encoding like utf-8?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("E:\\properties\\outfilename.txt"), "ISO-8859-7"));
```